# Efficient and pythonic way to search through a long string

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have created some code to search through a string and return True if there is an emoji in the string. The strings are found in a column in a pandas dataframe, and one can assume the string and the length of the dataframe could be arbitrarily long. I then create a new column in my dataframe with these boolean results.

Here is my code:

```
import emoji

contains_emoji = []
            
for row in df['post_text']:
    emoji_found = False
    for char in row:
        if emoji.is_emoji(char):
            emoji_found = True
            break
    contains_emoji.append(emoji_found)

df['has_emoji'] = contains_emoji
```

In an effort to get slicker, I was wondering if anyone could recommend a faster, shorter, or more pythonic way of searching like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `emoji.emoji_count()`:

```py
import emoji

# Create example dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'post_text':['', '', 'text ', 'abc']})

# Create column based on emoji within text
df['has_emoji'] = df['post_text'].apply(lambda x: emoji.emoji_count(x) > 0)

# print dataframe
print(df)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
  post_text  has_emoji
0                True
1                True
2    text        True
3       abc        False
```

Comment: I didn't spot that there was a emoji_count function in the emoji package. As per the above comment, this seems pretty simple: ```df['has_emoji'] = df['post_text'].apply(lambda x: emoji.emoji_count(x) > 0)```

Comment: Yes - have updated to reflect this

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response. I will remember to read the package source code next time! :)

Comment: It was a team effort 

Answer (score 2):

why not just

```
df["has_emoji"] = df.post_text.apply(emoji.emoji_count) > 0
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Indeed this is the approach I have now taken. Accepting ScottC's answer due to detailed explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use str.contains with a regex pattern that matches any emoji:

```
df['has_emoji'] = df['post_text'].str.contains(r'[\U0001f600-\U0001f650]')
```

For reference here is a link to the source code for emoji.emoji_count(): https://github.com/carpedm20/emoji/blob/master/emoji/core.py

Comment: I dont think this search text work with all emojis.